# file_get_contents() not able to fetch data?

Tags: php, json

I searched several posts similar to this but could not find an answer. I am probably missing out something small.

I am trying to read JSON contents from a URL as shown by my code:

```
$uri = "http://worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=schruns,austria&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=8f2d1ea151085304102710";
echo "URI: [$uri] <br/>";

$file = file_get_contents($uri);
$error = error_get_last();
echo $error['message'];
```

If I open the URL in a browser, I can see the JSON contents of it. But the above mentioned code does not work. `$file` has a value of `false`. The error message is:
`file_get_contents(http://worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=schruns,austria&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=8f2d1ea151085304102710) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory.`

Any suggestions? NOTE: my `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1` if it matters.

Edit:
Here is the entire PHP file.
http://pastebin.com/zCKEP9kG

Also, there is an fopen() in the code which opens an http file just fine.

Comment: Are you sure `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1`? If you set it to that yourself you probably need to restart your webserver (assuming PHP is running on some server here).

Comment: @ascii-lime: Yes I am sure. I checked it via ini_get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code, mate - it runs fine locally on my setup and I can get the file, and can do whatever I like with it.

Try it running on a different host - may be your php.ini is messed up and is messing up the script as well.. Or may be you've got problem with some other spot of the source.. may be if you shared the entire file source, or at least a bigger chunk of it..

Cheers!

Comment: I have added the entire PHP file. Note that there is an fopen()  called in the beginning of the code which works fine.

Comment: I tried running it on a different host. It worked. Maybe, as you say, my php.ini is messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code, i think you can proceed further with this now --

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=schruns,austria&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=8f2d1ea151085304102710";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

@ascii-lime

[image]

its for @ascii-lime--

Check this (Edit#2)

[image: Edit 2]

Comment: That's not going to work if `file_get_contents` is reading the file in the first place.

Comment: @ascii-lime I atleast tested this code at my end and its working check screenshot

Comment: Yes, it worked for you, because `file_get_contents` worked for you. The OP's original code should also work for you.

Comment: @ascii-lime Yes very true..this is what i thought but i when i run at my end in wont..so i just put that thing and it clicks..fst solution atleast for me..but let me check the breakpoints now :)

Comment: @ascii-lime I just posted the o/p from Akash code..with error_reporting(E_ALL); but it wont work for me

Comment: @ascii-lime interested to know your comments on this

Answer (score -2):

Try This :

```
   <?php
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json = file_get_contents('http://worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=schruns,austria&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=8f2d1ea151085304102710');
        echo $json;
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Nirav, No it does not work for me. Does it work for you without the header() line?

Comment: I think there are some mistake in your site . Its working me fine. And I use also

Comment: Nirav, I have added the entire PHP file, can you have a look at it once?